# "mysql 8.0" local infile fails I tried and display the settings. Could it be permission issues?

Tags: mysql, centos, load-data-infile

The following is my session I have the data located in the dir with owner/group of mysql
    mysql -u root -p
    Enter password: 
    Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
    Your MySQL connection id is 8
    Server version: 8.0.18 MySQL Community Server - GPL

```
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> set global local_infile = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use SSC;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> load data local infile '/storage/temp/myest1.csv' into table SSC fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines;
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
mysql> show variables like "local_infile";
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> load data local infile '/storage/temp/myest1.csv' into table SSC;
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
mysql> load data local infile 'myest1.csv' into table SSC;
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
mysql> SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@global.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /storage/temp/            |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the LOCAL option with LOAD DATA INFILE, then the `secure_file_priv` isn't used for the location of the file you load. The file is loaded by the client, so the path you use is not on the server, it's on the client. If you give a relative path, it's relative to the current working directory when you started the client.

However, both the server and the client must enable the `--local-infile` option.

You've set the option in the server, but you also need to set it in the client like this:

```
mysql --local-infile -u root -p
```

---

I think the error message you got is pretty unhelpful. I logged a bug about it:

[Bug #94396 Error message too broad: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94396)

Please vote up that bug report if you agree!

Comment: Thank you the command worked. I ran the process and during the load the log file filled the /tmp area. I cleaned it up redefined the tmp location and bounced the server. Now I am back to the same error!

Comment: mysql --local-infile -u root -p
Enter password: 

Server version: 8.0.18 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use SSC;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> load data local infile '/storage/temp/myest1.csv' into table SSC;
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Comment: I have reset the tmp location back to the original /tmp and restarted mysql and still no difference. IS this error a default else?

Comment: Is the `local_infile` option set in the server since you restarted it? It must be enabled in the server _and_ you must specify it as a client option.